# Ошибка com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Не могу запустить jar файл приложения JavaFX+Hibernate

Tags: java, javafx, hibernate, maven

Мое приложение использует JAVAFX и hibernate для работы с БД.Это первый проект ,который я с javaFx собираю другие технологии.
При создании jar файла и запуске без обращения к классу DbWork(), где используется hibernate проблем нет.Но при подключении этого класса и попытке запустить jar файл происходят ошибки:

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLo
ader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:197)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:246)
        at org.example.DbWork.<init>(DbWork.java:13)
        at org.example.App.main(App.java:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionD
omain)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        ... 45 more

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.r
eflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:97)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:246)
        at org.example.DbWork.<init>(DbWork.java:13)
        at org.example.App.main(App.java:30)
        ... 11 more
Exception running application org.example.App
```

В решении проблемы я пытался написать module-info.java,так же без результатов:

```
module Boolean_Calculate_Maven{
 exports Boolean_Calculate_Maven;
 requires javafx.graphics;
 requires javafx.web;
 requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
 requires java.naming;
 requires java.sql;
   requires lombok;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.fxml;
   opens App to javafx.fxml;
   opens DbWork to org.hibernate.orm.core;
}
```

Jar файл у меня запускается в терминале так:

```
java --module-path "D:\Soft\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web -jar Boolean_Calculate_Maven.jar
```

Иначе выводится:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

[image: В структуре в output layout все есть]
В структуре в output layout все есть
Мой главный класс:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
public class App extends Application {
    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("mainScene"), 640, 350);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DbWork();
        launch();
    }
}
```

Dbwork-есть класс в котором задействовам hibernate.

```
public class DbWork {
    SessionFactory factory=null;
    public DbWork() {
        try{
            factory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            UsersDao usersDao=new UsersDao(factory);
            final Users users=new Users();
            users.setUsername("userr");
            users.setPassword("123");
            usersDao.create(users);

         // usersDao.delete("userr");
        }finally {
            if(factory!=null)
                factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Затем я пытался загрузить дополнительные зависимости в pom которые могли бы решить проблему исходя из ошибок,но без результата:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Boolean_Calculate_Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.6</version>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Структура приложения:

[image: Структура]

Comment: Ничего не знаю про гибернейт, но ошибка говорит о том, что на момент обращения программы какого-то метода не существует, либо он вызывается неправильно, вы можете поменять местами new DbWork();
        launch(); ?

Comment: А для создания JFX артефактов, так и надо выбирать JavaFXApplication, там есть такой варинат

Comment: Да,я пробовал менять местами new DbWork(); launch().Но launch() работает ,как я понял, по типу потока,поэтому он не дает запуститься new DbWork() до своего завершения.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте обернуть launch в Platform.runLater( ( )->launch();)); или же его внутреннюю структуру, можно так же унаследовать класс от Task

Comment: Решили проблему ?

Comment: Я попробовал в отдельном потоке запустить процессы hibernate.При компиляции и запуске работает в другом потоке.Но при форматировании в jar, так же проблема.Я думаю ,что с настройкой конфигураций что-то не так.Ошибка все та же:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionD
omain)

Comment: Вы пробовали создавать атрефакт JavaFXApplication ?

Comment: Да.конечно.Изначально он у меня и был.Там все нужные maven зависимости отображаются.